# Should messaging classes be immutable?

Tags: c#, .net, messaging, immutability

When I say messaging classes I mean classes that are used strictly to get sent and be consumed by a consumer (or handler).

Often I see tutorials on service buses (e.g. NServiceBus) that simply make *heavy* use of automatic properties when creating new messages. In my eyes once a message is sent there is no reason to change. If *any* changes should occur to the information the message contains then it seems fair to have to create a new message and sent it again.

Should they be immutable?

Comment: Automatic properties and *observed* immutability need not be mutually exclusive. `{ get; private set; }` If the class contains no methods and is strictly a DTO, then the class is effectively immutable post-construction.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: True, but having readonly fields backing the properties properties allows this to be compiler enforced, and also makes a stronger statement to future developers that this was the intent.

Comment: @Reed - Also true, but it involves more boilerplate code than you might want to write for a simple DTO. If I was worried that the intent is not obvious, I might leave a small comment. (I might do that anyway even if using explicit readonly fields, as other developers *still* might not clue in).

Comment: Sometimes it will be necessary for one of the recipients of a message to make changes that are visible to other recipients.  For example, one might have a message which asks "Does anyone mind if I do X", and has a mutable `Cancel` property.  If there are five document windows, each of which would ask "Save ___ before closing YES/NO/CANCEL" and the user clicks "CANCEL" on the first one, the other four should observe that `Cancel` has been set to `True` and skip their prompts.  While there are other ways of implementing the pattern, using a mutable `Cancel` field or property is the simplest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many advantages to making these classes immutable.

Messaging systems tend to be something that can easily be made parallel or asynchronous in their delivery.  Any time you're introducing threading, immutability can provide a huge level of safety and prevent a lot of common mistakes.

> In my eyes once a message is sent there is no reason to change

If this is your usage scenario, then I would definitely tend to work with immutable data types.  I, personally, try to only make mutable types when there is a valid reason to have mutabililty.  Otherwise, I always prefer immutability due to the flexibility it brings and the safety it provides when improving the systems that use the type later (ie: introducing concurrency).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they should. There is no reason a message can be changed after their creation, just as you explained.
Also messages are normally used for abstraction and/or multithreading. By not making them immutable you take away the benefits immutability provides (e.g. thread safety).